# how to calculate the total of two incremented values from two different loops?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calculates sum of input values. In this form I have checkboxes and number type inputs. I'm able to make this function work with either only checkboxes or textboxes but not both at the same time. The two input types enter in conflict. It's probably very trivial but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help?

js

```js
$(document).on("change", ".calculate", function () {
  calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
  //input type number
  var textboxsum = 0;

  //input type checkbox
  var addonsum = 0;

  //iterate through each input
  $(".calculate").each(function () {
    //get input type
    var type = this.getAttribute("data-type");

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if (type === "room") {
        //add amount $35 per room
        var amount = parseFloat(this.value * 35);
      } else if (type === "addon") {
        var input = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          if (this.checked) {
            //10$ per addon
            addonsum += parseFloat(this.value * 10);
          }
        }
      }

      textboxsum += parseFloat(amount);
    }
  });

  //addup the two totals
  var totalAmount = textboxsum + addonsum;

  //.toFixed() roundoff to 2 decimal
  $(".total_amount").html(totalAmount.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>book a vacation house</h3>
<hr>
Total : <span class="total_amount"></span>
<hr>
<input type="number" data-type="room" class="calculate" min="0" placeholder="Number of Rooms">
<hr>
Fireplace
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr>
Pool
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr>
Jacuzzi
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr>
Mini Bar
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few issues in the code, and you can use parseInt instead of parseFloat

```js
$('.calculate').change(function() {
  let amount = 0;

  $(".calculate").each(function() {
    const type = this.getAttribute('data-type');

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
      if (type === 'room') {
        //add amount $35 per room
        amount = parseInt(this.value, 10) * 35;
      } else if (type === 'addon' && this.checked) {
        amount += parseInt(this.value, 10) * 10;
      }
    }
  });

  $(".total_amount").html(amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>book a vacation house</h3>

<hr>

Total : <span class="total_amount">0</span>

<hr>

<input type="number" data-type="room" class="calculate" min="0" placeholder="Number of Rooms">


<hr>

Fireplace
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">

<hr>

Pool
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">

<hr>

Jacuzzi
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">

<hr>

Mini Bar
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `var amount = 0;` at top inside `.each()`. The reason you are getting `NaN` when type is not room then it will not execute code from `if(type==='room')` where you have declared `amount` and in end you have used `textboxsum += parseFloat(amount);`, so here `amount` will return `undefined` & textboxsum will become `NaN`.

Try it below.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.calculate', function() {
  calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
  //from input type number
  var textboxsum = 0;
  //from input type checkbox
  var addonsum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".calculate").each(function() {
    //get input type
    var type = this.getAttribute('data-type');
    
    // declare amount variable here
    var amount = 0; // <-- Change
    
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if (type === 'room') {
        //add amount $35 per room
        // do not declare variable here. just use it
        amount = parseFloat((this.value) * 35);
      } else
      if (type === 'addon') {
        var input = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          if (this.checked) {
            //10$ per addon
            addonsum += parseFloat((this.value) * 10);
          }
        }
      }
      textboxsum += parseFloat(amount);
    }
  });

  //addup the two totals
  var totalAmount = textboxsum + addonsum;
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal
  $(".total_amount").html(totalAmount.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>book a vacation house</h3>
<hr>Total : <span class="total_amount"></span>
<hr>
<input type="number" data-type="room" class="calculate" min="0" placeholder="Number of Rooms">
<hr>Fireplace
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr> Pool
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr> Jacuzzi
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
<hr> Mini Bar
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" data-type="addon" class="calculate">
```